# django smart select not working in admin

Tags: python, django

I am using python 3.6 with django 2.1 version. Already I have install smart select library. But when I am trying use my admin side model form it's showing java script error.

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: chainedfk is not defined
    at initItem (bindfields.js:12)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (bindfields.js:31)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (bindfields.js:30)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: Yes. We need to modify core library Js file.

Comment: Mine miraculously started working again without changing anything...